# How to pass the ng-repeat value or ID to my appended element? It this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, sql-server

I have ng repeat table with 5 datas from my select query and condition on my datas. I just want to get the ng-repeat value and ID and transfer it to my appended element. I'm new in Angularjs and HTML hope you guys can help. Appreciate much help.

This is my HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered kl">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>VALUE</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in mySelectData">
         <td>{{d.ID}}</td>
         <td>{{d.VALUE}} <p id="dataColor">Color</p> </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my controller:

```
if(interval == 2000) {
    $('#dataColor').empty();
    $('#dataColor').append('<label> the color is {{d.VALUE}}</label>'
else {
    $('#dataColor').empty();
    $('#dataColor').append('<label> the color will be changed!</label>'
}
```

Output should be: (in my first load)

```
+--------+-----------+
|   ID   |   Value   |
+--------+-----------+
|   1    |   black   |
+--------+-----------+
|   2    |   red     |
+--------+-----------+
|   3    |   blue    |
+--------+-----------+
|   4    |   white   |
+--------+-----------+
|   5    |   red     |
+--------+-----------+
```

(in my 2nd load or after 2secs)

```
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   ID   |   Value                     |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   1    |   black  the color is black |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   2    |   red    the color is red   |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   3    |   blue   the color is blue  |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   4    |   white  the color is white |
+--------+-----------------------------+
|   5    |   red    the color is red   |
+--------+-----------------------------+
```

finally

```
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   ID   |   Value                             |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   1    |   black  the color will be changed! |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   2    |   red    the color will be changed! |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   3    |   blue   the color will be changed! |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   4    |   white  the color will be changed! |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
|   5    |   red    the color will be changed! |
+--------+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data attributes][1]

Add a data attribute to the html :

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in mySelectData">
    <td>{{d.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{d.VALUE}} <p id="dataColor-{{$index}}" class="js-color-change" data-color="{{d.VALUE}}">Color</p> </td>
</tr>
```

[Retrieve values from data attributes in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448914/retrieving-the-data-from-data-attribute-with-angularjs)

inside you if conditions you can query using `class` instead if `id` and change the values by using data attributes

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change ID  "dataColor" to class "dataColor"  because ID is not duplicate.

```
if(interval == 2000) {
    $('.dataColor').empty();
    $('.dataColor').append('<label> the color is {{d.VALUE}}</label>'
else {
    $('.dataColor').empty();
    $('.dataColor').append('<label> the color will be changed!</label>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the below code, Also please check this [plinker link](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/6serW57T2U0xBHWZ) for you given scenario working example.

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.mySelectData = [{
    ID: 1,
    VALUE: 'black'
  }, {
    ID: 2,
    VALUE: 'red'
  }, {
    ID: 3,
    VALUE: 'blue'
  }, {
    ID: 4,
    VALUE: 'white'
  }, {
    ID: 5,
    VALUE: 'green'
  }];
  $timeout(function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.mySelectData, function(item){
      item.MESSAGE = "the color is " + item.VALUE;
    });
  }, 2000);
  $timeout(function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.mySelectData, function(item){
      item.MESSAGE = "the color will be changed!";
    });
  }, 4000);
```

**Template:**

```
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>VALUE</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="d in mySelectData">
            <td>{{d.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{d.VALUE}} {{d.MESSAGE}} </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```